# When I scale to uiwebview , scroll to much

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I want to scale uiwebview.When I scale uiwebview on webViewDidFinishLoad method ,uiwebview scalling good. But When I scroll to bottom ,scrolling is more than content.You can see on video what is problem . How can I solve this or any advice?

video : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fu4mbvscj72qm6i/IMG_0009.MOV

[image: Scrollbar and pageController]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollViewDetail.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollViewDetail.scrollEnabled=YES;
    self.scrollViewDetail.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollViewDetail.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    self.scrollViewDetail.tag=1498;
    CGRect frame=self.pageControlDetail.frame;
    frame.size.width=self.view.frame.size.width;
    self.pageControlDetail = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 3, self.view.frame.size.width, 25.0)];
    self.pageControlDetail.numberOfPages =self.haberLinks.count;
    self.pageControlDetail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.pageControlDetail.currentPage = self.currentPage;
    CGFloat pageWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    self.scrollViewDetail.delegate=nil; //setContentOffset yaptığında scrollViewDidScroll'a gitmemesi için
    [self.scrollViewDetail setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageWidth*self.currentPage,0) animated:YES];
    self.scrollViewDetail.delegate=self;

    [self.containerPageControl addSubview:self.pageControlDetail];


    self.scrollViewDetail.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * bannerCount, self.scrollViewDetail.frame.size.height-self.containerPageControl.frame.size.height-20);
    self.pageControlDetail.numberOfPages =bannerCount;

   UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*self.currentPage,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,self.scrollViewDetail.frame.size.height)];
    //webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    webView.tag = 1001;
    webView.delegate=self;
    webView.scrollView.tag=10002;
    webView.scrollView.frame=webView.frame;
    webView.scrollView.delegate=self;
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    [self.scrollViewDetail addSubview:webView]; 
}


#pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{

    //only scroll to up and bottom
    if (sender.tag==10002)
    {
        NSLog(@"sdscjjkshdjhhjdfs");
        sender.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

        CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(0, sender.contentSize.height);
        [sender setContentSize:scrollableSize];

    }

    if (sender.tag==1498)
    {
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollViewDetail.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scrollViewDetail.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.currentPage=page;
        self.pageControlDetail.currentPage = page;
         NSLog(@"curent page is %i",page);
    }

}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if (webView.tag==1001)
    {

        CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
        CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

        float scale = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;
        if (scale < 0.9) {
            NSLog(@"Zoom out fix for web view: %f", scale);

            webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale;
            webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scale;
            webView.scrollView.zoomScale = scale;
        }
    }

}
```

htmlString example :

```
<table width="510" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top"><p><a href="http://www.haberaktuel.com/yetenek-sizsiniz-rusca-tercuman-rafet-youtube-yetenek-sizsiniz-turkiye-kirgiz-cocuk-haberi-828297.html"><img src="http://www.haberaktuel.com/images//news/r-rafet-300200-804679.jpg" width="
]]>
<![CDATA[
72" height="48" style="border: 1px #000000 solid;" hspace="2" align="left"></a>
 Yetenek Sizsiniz Türkiye'yi<strong> kahkahaya boğan Tercüman Rafet </strong>yine sahnede.</p>
 <p>
 Az sonra <strong>videoyu bu sayfadan</strong> bulabilirsiniz.</p>
 <p>
 Bu arada Rekabet Kurulu kararına göre MNG TV Yayıncılık, MNG Reklam Pazarlama ve Prodüksiyon, MNG Medya ve TV Yayıncılık ve Onsekiz Reklam Prodüksiyon Medya Yapımevi, hisselerinin yüzde 90'ı Sekiz Medya Holding A.Ş., yüzde 10'u da Sekiz Prodüksiyon ve Reklam A.Ş. tarafından devralındı.</p>
 <p>
 Acun Ilıcalı ile TV8'in sahibi Mehmet Nazif Günal arasındaki bir süredir devam eden satış süreci 14 Kasım'da sonuçlanmış ve ikili kendi arasında anlaşama varmıştı. Daha sonra da bu anlaşma son onay için Rekabet Kurulu'na gönderildi.</p>
 <p>
 Acun Ilıcalı, şu an Star TV'ye O Ses Türkiye, Survivor ve Yetenek Sizsiniz programlarını hazırlıyor. Geçtiğimiz yıl gelir vergisi rekortmenleri listesinde ilk 100'e giren ünlüler arasında da yer alan Ilıcalı, listede 4 milyon 604 bin TL vergi tahakkuku ile 31. sırada yer almıştı.</p>
 <p>
 <span style="color:#0000ff;"><strong>ESKİ VİDEO:</strong></span></p>
 <p>
 <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/G7sqCNzdGj0" width="600"></iframe></p>
 <p>
 Öte yandan Kamuoyunun sanatçı Ebru Gündeş'in eşi olarak tanıdığı iş adamı Reza Zarrab, operasyonla gözaltına alınmadan önce eşine Acun Ilıcalı'nın uçağından almış. İstanbul 18. Sulh Mahkemesi'nin aldığı karar gereği el konulanlar arasında bu şirket üzerine kayıtlı Challenger 300 tipi özel jet var. Are Havacılık'ın operasyon yetkisinin bulunmaması nedeniyle işletmesi MNG Jet tarafından gerçekleştiriliyordu.</p>
 <p>
 Uçağın TC- RZA olan tescili, Reza Zerrab'ın adının harflerinden oluşuyor. Kanadalı Bombardier şirketinin imalatı jet 2009 model. ABD'de N284JC tescili ile uçan Challenger 300, Eylül 2012'de Reza Zarrab tarafından satın alınarak Türkiye'ye getirildi. Are Havacılık'ı büyütmeyi hedefleyen Reza Zarrab, 2015'te şirketinin filosunu 3 uçağa çıkartmayı planlıyordu.</p>
 <p>
 2009 model Challenger 300'ün piyasa değeri uçuş saatine bağlı olarak 12 milyon dolar ile 16 milyon dolar arasında değişiyor. 2013 model fabrika çıkışlı Challenger 300'ün liste satış fiyatı ise 24 milyon dolar.</p>
 <p>
 2009 model Challenger 300'ün kabini, 8 yolcu kapasiteli. İç kabin yüksekliği 1 metre 85 santimetre. Uydu telefonunun da yer aldığı uçak 5 bin 741 kilometre menzile sahip. 13 bin 716 metre yüksekliğe çıkabilen jet, saatte en fazla 870 kilometre hızla uçabiliyor.</p>
 <p>
 AYNI U&Ccedil;AKTAN ACUN'DA DA VAR</p>
 <p>
 Ünlü televizyoncu Acun Ilıcalı, geçen ay Cessna Citation XL tipi iş jetini satarak tip büyütmüş, Challenger 300 almıştı. Bu tip uçağın diğer kullanıcıları arasında Mehmet Emin Karamehmet'in &Ccedil;ukurova Grubu, Lucien Arkas'ın Arkas Havacılık ile Mehmet Sepil'e ait Genel Enerji gibi şirketler bulunuyor.</p>
 <p>
 Bu arada Daha önce Var Mısın Yok Musun yarışmasıyla tanınan ve Acun Ilıcalı'nın çeşitli tanıtım filmleriyle ekrana çıkan Furkan Dede, TV 8'de sunucu oldu. Furkan Dede'nin sunduğu yeni eğlence programı 'Oynat Bakalım' haftanın üç günü Pazartesi, &Ccedil;arşamba ve Cuma günleri 17.45'de TV 8 ekranlarında olacak. Oynat Bakalım'da birbirinden ilginç, komik ve sosyal medyada tıklanma rekoru kıran videolar ekrana gelecek.</p>
 </td></tr></table>
```